# Issuing 1-1 eth for token problem

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.5.x, solidity-0.6.x, solidity-0.7.x

```
pragma solidity 0.6.6;

// import "./XYZToken.sol";

contract Vault {
    
    mapping(address => uint256) balanceOf;
    mapping(address => bool) hasDepositedEther;
    mapping(address => bool) hasntDepositedEther;
    
    
    function depositEther(uint _amount) public payable returns(bool success) {
        balanceOf[msg.sender] += _amount;
        hasDepositedEther[msg.sender] = true;
        hasntDepositedEther[msg.sender] = false;
        return true;
    }
    
      function issueTokens() public view returns(bool success) {
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] != 0 ether, "You need to deposit Ether in order to receive tokens");
        require(hasntDepositedEther[msg.sender] == false, "You need to deposit Ether in order to receive tokens");
        require(hasDepositedEther[msg.sender] == true, "You need to deposit Ether in order to receive tokens");
        
        balanceOf[msg.sender].transfer
            
        return true;
    }

}
```

Where balanceOf[msg.sender].transfer is, how can I turn that into code where I can issue tokens 1-to-1 for each eth they've deposited?

Comment: Regardless, you need to change `balanceOf[msg.sender] += _amount` to `balanceOf[msg.sender] += msg.value`.

Comment: Actually, it is not regardless, because once you do that, this function (`depositEther`) becomes the one issuing 1-1 tokens per user ether, and you can get rid of the other function (`issueTokens`).

Comment: @goodvibration how would I be able to issue tokens exactly, that's what I'm stuck on. I actually ended up removing the issueToken function and having only the depositEther the only one.

Comment: With `balanceOf[y] += x`, you are issuing `x` more wei of your token to `y`. I suggest that you read the ERC20 standard.